# How to display a div inside asp.net pageload

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to visible a div within aspx.cs C# file.here i'm using stored procedure to get the product list with prices.So i defined a div call sizemenu in the aspx page.How can i visible this within the particular function. is there any possible ways?

```
        Product product = new Product();
        product.Id =Convert.ToInt64(labl.Text);

        Hashtable parameterList = new Hashtable();
        parameterList.Add("saleId", index.saleid.Id);//sale id
        parameterList.Add("productId", product.Id);
        parameterList.Add("productSizeId", null);
        parameterList.Add("costPrice", null);
        parameterList.Add("salesPrice", null);
        //parameterList.Add("offerDetailId", null);
        parameterList.Add("offerFound", -1);
        parameterList.Add("currentDate", DateTimeUtil.GetFormattedString(((Sale)index.saleid).Date.Date));
        parameterList.Add("currentTime", DateTimeUtil.GetFormatedTimeString(Convert.ToDateTime(((Sale)index.saleid).Time)));
        parameterList.Add("day", Const.GetDay(((Sale)index.saleid).Date.DayOfWeek));
        parameterList.Add("productSizePointValue", null);
        parameterList.Add("isOfferUser", "False");
        parameterList.Add("recipeSelection", null);
        psList.SelectUsingSP(Global.sess, "SqlProInsertProductSizeToSale", parameterList);


        if (psList.Count == 0)
        {

        }
        else if (psList.Count == 1)
        {

        }
        else if (psList.Count > 1)
        {

           //want to display the div here   
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take Div  in .aspx page

```
  <div  id="divdisplay" runat="server" visible="false">
    //write your code//or html code
  </div>
```

in aspx.cs File

```
divdisplay.visible=false;
 if (psList.Count == 0)
        {

        }
        else if (psList.Count == 1)
        {

        }
        else if (psList.Count > 1)
        {
           divdisplay.visible=true;
           //divdisplay.innerHtml="vcxcvcxvcbvc.......";
           //want to bind html  div from code Behind
        }
```

above code helps you to make it working.

Comment: it's not getting the div id into cs file? how do i get it?

Answer (score 1):

In your aspx Page for the div which you want to show it in the cs code behind..
make sure you add `Id` for the `div` and also another attribute `runat="server"`
with that attribute only you can able to find the div id in code behind

**Aspx Page**

```
<div id="dvtoshow" runat="server" visible="false"></div>
```

**In code Behind**

```
if (psList.Count == 0)
        {

        }
        else if (psList.Count == 1)
        {

        }
        else if (psList.Count > 1)
        {
           dvtoshow.visible=true;
           //dvtoshow.innerHtml="your Text";

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yourdivid.style.add("display",""); //to show
yourdivid.style.add("display","none"); //to hide
```

Comment: Not working! i want to give a command in page load to display the div